# addClass - can add multiple classes on same div?

Tags: jquery

jQuery add multiple class

This is my current code, I know its wrong code

```
$('.page-address-edit').addClass('test1').addClass('test2');
```

Comment: This is not wrong, but it can be simply replaced with addClass('test1 test2'); http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: im sorry , updated my question

Answer (score 205, accepted):

```
$('.page-address-edit').addClass('test1 test2 test3');
```

[Ref- jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 35):

You can do

```
$('.page-address-edit').addClass('test1 test2');
```

More [here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

> More than one class may be added at a time, separated by a space, to the set of matched elements, like so:
>
> ```
> $("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
> ```

Answer (score 13):

You can add multiple classes by separating classes names by spaces

```
$('.page-address-edit').addClass('test1 test2 test3');
```

Answer (score 12):

You code is ok only except that you can't add same class `test1`.

```
$('.page-address-edit').addClass('test1').addClass('test2'); //this will add test1 and test2
```

And you could also do

```
$('.page-address-edit').addClass('test1 test2');
```