# How to modify this JS code to add/remove more than one class on scroll up/down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to change the height of my header on scroll down and it works great. The only issue is that I would like to have the possibility to remove and add more than one class. Is it possible? How could I achieve that?
Many thanks,

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var header = $(".header");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 5) {
            header.removeClass('bigheight').addClass("shortheight");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("shortheight").addClass('bigheight');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009820/addclass-can-add-multiple-classes-on-same-div][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009820/addclass-can-add-multiple-classes-on-same-div

This should point you in the right direction :)

Comment: cant you just do  header.removeClass('bigheight').addClass("shortheight ONEMORE");

Comment: Argh, I should have thought about that ;-) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add / remove more than one class by separating with a space:

```
header.addClass("shortheight class2");
header.removeClass("shortheight class2");
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/