# Optimization of the form of validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I want to do validation, which displays an error message in the placeholder of the input.
I write code to check the 1 form field, and change its placeholder if it's empty. How can this be optimized for three fields?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() { if($("#name").val()==''||$("#name").val()==null){ $("#name").val("").attr("placeholder","An error occured!").addClass("changePlaceColor1").addClass("changePlaceColor2").addClass("changePlaceColor3").addClass("changePlaceColor4");    }  })  })
```

[here is my code in the codepen](https://codepen.io/volya/pen/NAOmEy)

Also want to do that to these changes remain until you press input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a class="validation" to all your fields that need to be validated, and change your js to this

```
<form>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="test message1" data-error="1" class="validation" />
  <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="test message1" data-error="2" class="validation"/>
  <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="test message1" data-error="3" class="validation"/>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    $(".validation").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==''||$(this).val()==null){
          $(this).val("")
            .attr("placeholder",$(this).data("error"))
            .addClass("changePlaceColor1")
            .addClass("changePlaceColor2")
            .addClass("changePlaceColor3")
            .addClass("changePlaceColor4");
            e.preventDefault();
          }
    });
  })
});
```

No reason to add validation for each field sepperatly, add a basic validation code and loop through all applicable fields. Less time the same piece of code you have, the better your code is

EDIT:
Custom error text for each input through data attribute

Comment: Yes, that I had in mind) Thanks
And somehow still possible to add to each input his message?

Comment: example changed as such. Just store the text in a data attribute and call the elements data attribute instead of hardcoded message

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {  
    $('input').each(function(){
      if($(this).val()=='' || $(this).val()==null){
        $(this).attr('placeholder','An error occured!').addClass('changePlaceColor');
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.changePlaceColor::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:    red;
}
.changePlaceColor:-moz-placeholder {
    color:    red;
}
.changePlaceColor:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color:    red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="test message1"/>
  <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="test message1"/>
  <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="test message1"/>
  <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for editing class in the css.
Corrected in the code)

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** You can use `$('form').on('submit' , function(){ //code here });` [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785241/difference-between-handling-form-submit-or-an-input-type-submit-click-e)

**2nd:** You need to use [e.preventDefault();](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent reload

**3rd:** You need to use `.each()` posted in [@Elentriel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38806844/3385827) and [@jonju answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38806881/3385827)

**4th:** With `addClass()` you can use `.addClass("changePlaceColor1 changePlaceColor2 changePlaceColor4");` [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009820/addclass-can-add-multiple-classes-on-same-div)