# Adding multiple classes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why there is an option to add multiple classes? It will not affect anything...why does it even exist? I have tried to use it, but it is truly useless.

Comment: Why.... wouldn't there be? Just because you don't understand something doesn't make it useless. `$(element).addClass("class1 class2")`.  Voting to close as not a question.

Comment: Why do you think it's useless? Do you mean it doesn't do what the documentation says it should?

Comment: Why a command that sets multiple classes will be useful if you can't set multiple classes?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009820/addclass-can-add-multiple-classes-on-same-div
This may be helpful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why a command that sets multiple classes will be useful if you can't set multiple classes?*

I don't understand this post, it's not a question but as you can see you can define multiple classes. 
If you don't understand how to use it, here's the documentation link : https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myDiv').addClass('div1 div2 div3');
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: #888;
}
.div2 {
  color: #FFF;
}
.div3 {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">Test</div>
```

Comment: Didn't know that you can add multiple classes 